# Kubuntu 20.04. Ubuntu Studio installer freezes at "setting up jackd2"

Tags: kubuntu, ubuntu-studio, jack

The subject says it all. Wondering if there is a work around. Dell Vostro 3350 laptop.
[image: setting up jackd2]

Comment: There is no 20.08.  Do you mean 20.04?

Comment: Oops. I stand corrected. Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you simply install Ubuntu Studio from its own iso file (instead of sqeezing it into Kubuntu)? You can try it live or persistent live or installed into a separate drive or partition.

Comment: 1) This is recommended by Ubuntu, so if it doesn’t work, it needs fixing.
2) XFCE just doesn’t do it for me. It is a waste of time and a waste of space. With things that you can do with one click or key command in KDE, it takes three in XFCE. Try to add a launcher in KDE and compare it to XFCE. You have to jump through more hoops. Anyway, there was also a decision made a couple of years ago to use KDE in Ubuntu Studio, but that never came to anything for some reason.

Comment: When you installed ubuntustudio-installer from the command line, it should have pulled-in ubuntustudio-controls which pulls-in jackd2. Installer should not have had to install jackd2 at all, so this shows me that you installed ubuntustudio-installer without any of its dependencies.

Comment: There seems to be a lot of confusion about this installer. Probably Ubuntu’s fault. I installed KDE Neon and then used Ubuntu’s new method of adding Ubuntu Studio to an install. This is not the installer for the entire Ubuntu Studio distro, this is the zenity based installer that Ubuntu has developed to add Ubuntu Studio packages by category to an Ubuntu based system, regardless of DE. This installer allows you to choose audio, video, etc. group packages and install them. You are not however, allowed to not install related packages as you describe. That is not the problem.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/UbuntuStudioInstaller

“ Ubuntu Studio includes Ubuntu Studio Installer by default. For other flavors, open a terminal and type:
sudo apt install ubuntustudio-installer

This will bring in other tools, such as Ubuntu Studio Controls which is required for audio configuration prep which is done after Ubuntu Studio Installer has been run.”

As described in the quote, the installer was trying to pull in jackd2 and configure the packages, but it choked on jackd2 for some reason. I.e. it’s broken and needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

When you installed ubuntustudio-installer from the command line, it should have pulled-in ubuntustudio-controls which pulls-in jackd2. Installer should not have had to install jackd2 at all, so this shows me that you installed ubuntustudio-installer without any of its dependencies. That's why it's stalled.

Answer (score 0):

I see that the ubuntustudio-installer has been updated so that jackd2 and a number of other dependencies now get pulled in when the ubuntustudio-installer is installed, so that they are loaded prior to running the ubuntustudio-installer. A bit of a kludge, but it worked when I tried it.